# wpf: how to make ComboBoxItems hold integers in xaml

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, selecteditem

ok, I must be having a brain freeze here...

I have a ComboBox with 6 items and I'm trying to bind the selected item to an integer value. Its not working, I suspect its because the ComboBoxItem's are strings. I don't feel like making a list in code behind just to fill this little box, so is there a way in xaml to tell the comboboxitems that they are holding integer numbers? Something like `<x:Int>2</x:Int>` maybe?

xaml:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SavedPrintTicket.PagesPerSheet}">
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>4</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>6</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>8</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>16</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the System namespace:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

And then your combo-box can contain integers like so:

```
<ComboBox>
   <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I'd like to emphasize that if you don't include the xmlns System namespace, sys:Int32 will be undefined.  I've seen other solutions that say to use sys:Int32, but fail to mention the namespace - making it seem like the solution doesn't work or isn't supported somehow.