# Best way to sort XML attributes consistently throughout XML files in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing, xaml

I am trying to write a Xaml parser that would sort all the attributes of every tags in xaml files to keep the code organized and consistent.

I have fairly limited knowledge of C# and LINQ as I'm a front-end designer / developer, not a C# guru.

As far as I know, xaml is XML therefore, this would work with just any xml files. I will have parameters that will let the user order the attributes.

I tried using Regexp, it didn't go too well, I then tried using "XElement.Parse", no luck. It seems to not like x:Name etc.

What would be the best way?

Comment: Since the order of attributes is irrelevant in xml, I'd first ask... why?

Comment: are you applying namespaces correctly in your custom parser?

Comment: @Marc-Gravell it is meaningful in terms of code readability and maintainability between different front-end developers working on a large project. Just as developers have guidelines and rules regarding code formatting, reading through a buttload of xaml constantly makes you realise how standardization of attributes order matters. It significantly speeds up changes implementation and bug fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please show your XAML.

I successfully parsed XAML with x:Key attribute and self:NullableBoolToStringConvreter node from [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731685/c-wpf-how-should-i-do-proper-checks-guards-casts-when-accessing-control-valu/).

Comment: This could be any xaml. I'm writing an attribute sorter, so that it works with any xaml files.

Comment: Of course this could be any xaml. But you mentioned that you got error on Parse method. I reproduced situation and my xaml document with x:Key, x:Name attributes was parsed successfuly. By the way why you are using XElement.Parse() instead of XDocument.Parse()?

Comment: That might have been XDocument parse yes, I'm not a 100% sure as I tried many different ways. Will try XElement's Parse.

Comment: Okay, once more. You were absolutely correct when mentioned that XAML is just XML. So functions XDocument.Load()/XDocument.Parse() should succesfully work with any XAML. If you have opposite examples - please post them here. Or your problem is in writing code that sorts attributes?

Comment: it worked, I just got tossed around a lot because I found code samples that were average. Do you know a good XElement article? thanks.

Comment: Actually no, but you could to check out this article http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/07/using-linq-to-xml-and-how-to-build-a-custom-rss-feed-reader-with-it.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, using the 4.0 .NET runtime:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/pitfalls_xml_4_0.aspx